# Bounding box should rotate - Skews instead

Tags: java, rotation, bounding-boxes

I have a method to rotate a sprite's bounding box around the center of the sprite (the sprite rotates and I need the bounding box to rotate with it. The sprite is rectangular).

Instead of being rotated, the bounding box is skewing wierdly. When the angle is 0 - the bounding box is a perfect rectangle. But when the angle changes, the bounding box is getting gradually skewed.

All of this happens in the object's `move()` method. This method is called every cycle of the game-loop. What I'm trying to do is this:

1. Move the sprite in the direction the user chose. (x += dx, y += dy).
2. Get the coordinates of the new center of the sprite.
3. Get coordinates for the four vertices of the **not-rotated-version**
   of the sprite.
4. Manipulate these coordinates, so they are now the vertices of the
   **rotated sprite**.

The coordinates that step 4 gives me, are used to create the bounding box (and temporarily draw it on the screen so I can see).

Somewhere, this fails. As I said, the bounding box doens't rotate. Instead, it skews (and maybe also rotates, not sure).

What could be the problem?

Code:

```
public void move(){

// Advance sprite.
x += dx;
y += dy;

// Get the new center point of the sprite.
centerx = x + width/2;
centery = y + height/2;

// Get the 4 vertices of the non-rotated version of the sprite.
xcoo[0] = (int) x;
xcoo[1] = (int) (x + width);
xcoo[2] = (int) (x + width);
xcoo[3] = (int) x;

ycoo[0] = (int) y;
ycoo[1] = (int) y;
ycoo[2] = (int) (y + height);
ycoo[3] = (int) (y + height);

// Manipulate each vertex, so it fits the rotated sprite.
for(int z=0;z<4;++z){

    xcoo[z] -= centerx;
    ycoo[z] -= centery;

    xcoo[z] = (xcoo[z] * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)) - ycoo[z] * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)));
    ycoo[z] = (xcoo[z] * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle)) + ycoo[z] * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle)));

    xcoo[z] += centerx;
    ycoo[z] += centery;

}

}
```

Help would be very appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `ycoo[z] = (xcoo[z] * ...` uses the `xcoo[z]` you modified the line before. Consider working on copies of `xcoo[z]` and `ycoo[z]` in the loop body and assign them out at the end of the iteration.

Comment: @LarsViklund In this case, you want to work on the modified `xcoo[z]`, since it's translating back to the origin.

Comment: @Byte56 As a clarification: in the loop, line 3 and 4 should use the `xcoo[z]` from line 1, but line 4 gets the `xcoo[z]` from line 3. The solution I intended to answer with before the question got prematurely locked was: `{ auto x_rel = xcoo[z] - centerx, y_rel = ycoo[z] - centery; auto x_new = (x_rel * ..); auto y_new = (x_rel * ..); xcoo[z] = x_new + centerx; ycoo[z] = y_new + centery; }`

Comment: @LarsViklund I see what you mean. Yes, that's certainly a bug. Sorry you didn't get to post an answer, but debugging questions aren't on topic here. Thanks for helping out anyway.